# Search Gmail for mail with attachments

Tags: search, gmail, imap, attachment

I have connected and logged in to gmail's imap server using openssl. I intend to search for all mails that have an attachment with them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMAP itself does not have a search term for that, but [Gmail's extended search support](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions) should allow you to search for messages with attachments.  You'll have to select the folder you're interested in:

```
a SELECT INBOX
```

Then use the GMail specific search command:

```
b UID SEARCH X-GM-RAW "has:attachment"
```

That should give you a list of UIDs of messages that have attachments.

Comment: If you wish to do this with baseline IMAP (no extensions) you'd need to `FETCH` the `BODYSTRUCTURE` for all messages, and parse that information looking for attachments.